# Read or save a PDF file uploaded to Flask

Tags: python, flask, form-data, pypdf, python-os

I'm uploading multiple files to flask using a form, I'm getting the file objects in the flask backend without a problem but the issue is I want to read the PDF files to extract text from them. I can't do it on the file objects I received from the form, another method I thought of was saving the file in the local storage then read them again when I did that using file.save(path, filename) it created an empty text file with the name - filename.pdf

```
app=Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '''
        <form method='POST' action='/saveData'>
        <input type='file' name='testReport'>
        <input type='submit'>
        </form>
    '''

@app.route('/saveData', methods=['POST'])
def saveData():
    if 'testReport' in request.files:
        testReport= request.files['testReport']
        #This isn't working, a text file is saved with the same name ,ending in pdf
        testReport.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], testReport.filename))       
        return f'<h1>File saved {testReport.filename}</h1>'
        
    else:
        return 'Not done'
```

How do we operate on PDF files after uploading them to flask ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How do we operate on PDF files after uploading them to flask ?*

You should treat them just like normal PDF files - if they were uploaded via Flask application or gathered using other method is irrelevant here. As you

*want to read the PDF files to extract text from them.*

you should use PDF text-extraction tool, for example [pdfminer.six](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/composable.html), as this is external module you need to install it first: `pip install pdfminer.six`

Comment: Is there a way to save the PDFs in my PC?

Comment: @ShashankPrasad according to [Flask Uploading Files Guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/) `form` should have `enctype` set to `multipart/form-data` (`<form enctype=multipart/form-data`...) whilst your has no enctype whatsever. You need to add correct [enctype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly follow the flask own way as mentioned [[here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/)]

This easily works with pdfs. Just don't forget to include your extension in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS